# QtAndroid: Grant Usb Permission in Android with Qt6

Tags: android, qt, qtandroidextras, rtl-sdr

in android programming you need to get usb permission before working with connected device to client device.
i am trying to connect a `hack-rf` to android device and use it... but first of all i need to get usb permission and detect that `hackrf`.

**setup:**
1- `qt6.3.0`
2- `ndk 21.3.6528147`
3- ui with QML

this is my c++ code to get permission of storage:

```
bool checkAppPermissions(QString permission)
{
    auto result = QtAndroidPrivate::checkPermission(permission).result();
    if (result == QtAndroidPrivate::Denied) {
        auto result2 = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission(permission).result();
        qDebug() << permission << result2;

        if (result2 == QtAndroidPrivate::Denied)
            return false;
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and it's usage:

```
checkAppPermissions("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
```

but i cannot get usb permisson this way.. its not working.

in `AndroidManifest.xml` i put these:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
```

also i think the permission that i had to get is `"com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"` but i dont know how should i Grant or request for that.

[this kotlin code](https://github.com/bastibl/android-fm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/bastibl/fmrx/MainActivity.kt#L113) works fine... it detects device and gets the permission but i don't know how it is working! or how can i implement it in Qt with cpp.

i also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22441518/8478206) but i dont know how he uses `C++ native side code` or `MyActivity.java`

could you help me to detect device and grant it's permission at run time.

Comment: You can take a look at this link https://tim37021.medium.com/using-kotlin-in-your-qt-project-299398c5b617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ask for USB permission you need to use the **Java** class called `UsbManager`.

In **Qt6**, they changed how [QJniObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjniobject.html) works, so it is kinda hard to find how to use it but here is what you need to do :

1. Get the context and usb manager object :

   ```
   QJniObject context = QtAndroidPrivate::context();
   if (context.isValid()) {
   QJniObject usbManager = context.callObjectMethod(
       "getSystemService",
       "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;",
       QJniObject::getStaticObjectField(
           "android/content/Context",
           "USB_SERVICE",
           "Ljava/lang/String;"
       ).object<jstring>()
   );
   ```
2. Iterate on the `deviceList` obtained from `usbManager` :

   ```
       QJniObject deviceList = usbManager.callObjectMethod(
           "getDeviceList",
           "()Ljava/util/HashMap;"
       );

       //Retrieve Java objects to be able to iterate deviceList
       QJniEnvironment env;
       jobject jMap = deviceList.object();
       jclass mapClass = env->GetObjectClass(jMap);
       jmethodID entrySet = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "entrySet", "()Ljava/util/Set;");
       jobject jEntrySet = env->CallObjectMethod(jMap, entrySet);
       jclass setClass = env->FindClass("java/util/Set");
       jmethodID iterator = env->GetMethodID(setClass, "iterator", "()Ljava/util/Iterator;");
       jobject jIterator = env->CallObjectMethod(jEntrySet, iterator);
       jclass iteratorClass = env->FindClass("java/util/Iterator");
       jmethodID hasNext = env->GetMethodID(iteratorClass, "hasNext", "()Z");
       jmethodID next = env->GetMethodID(iteratorClass, "next", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
       jclass entryClass = env->FindClass("java/util/Map$Entry");
       jmethodID getKey = env->GetMethodID(entryClass, "getKey", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
       jmethodID getValue = env->GetMethodID(entryClass, "getValue", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
   ```
3. Get your device object and obtain all information needed (if you want to print for debug or something else)

   ```
    while (env->CallBooleanMethod(jIterator, hasNext)) {
           jobject jEntry = env->CallObjectMethod(jIterator, next);
           jstring jDeviceName = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(jEntry, getKey));
           jobject jDevice = env->CallObjectMethod(jEntry, getValue);
           QJniObject device(jDevice);

           jint vendorId = device.callMethod<jint>("getVendorId", "()I");
           jint productId = device.callMethod<jint>("getProductId", "()I");
           QString manufacturer = (device.callMethod<jstring>("getManufacturerName", "()Ljava/lang/String;")).toString();
           QString productname = (device.callMethod<jstring>("getProductName", "()Ljava/lang/String;")).toString();
   ```
4. And this is how you request permission to a specific device

   ```
           jstring permissionString = env->NewStringUTF("org.qtproject.example.USB_PERMISSION");

           QJniObject intent("android/content/Intent");
           jclass stringClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
           jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(stringClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
           jobject stringObject = env->NewObject(stringClass, constructor, permissionString);
           intent.callMethod<void>("<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", stringObject);

           QJniObject permissionIntent("android/app/PendingIntent");
           jclass pendingIntentClass = env->FindClass("android/app/PendingIntent");
           jmethodID getBroadcastMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(pendingIntentClass, "getBroadcast", "(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/content/Intent;I)Landroid/app/PendingIntent;");
           permissionIntent = permissionIntent.callStaticObjectMethod(pendingIntentClass, getBroadcastMethod, context.object(), 0, intent.object(), 0);

           usbManager.callMethod<void>(
               "requestPermission",
               "(Landroid/hardware/usb/UsbDevice;Landroid/app/PendingIntent;)V",
               device.object(),
               permissionIntent.object()
               );
   ```